# how to retrieve list of records without making that many calls to api

Tags: json, rest, http

I was wondering if for swapi, or any api for that matter, I call http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/ , which returns a payload like so

```
{
    "climate": "Arid",
    "diameter": "10465",
    "gravity": "1 standard",
    "name": "Tatooine",
    "orbital_period": "304",
    "population": "200000",
    "residents": [
        "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/",
        "https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/",
        ...
    ],
    "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/"
}
```

If I'm interested in getting just the names of the residents related to planet 1 for processing, would I need to make a separate call to each of these urls to get everything and then process these items to extract the resident names?  I was hoping for a way to do so without having to make a call per resident name.

Comment: I believe you can't do so unless the api has an endpoint that return the list of residents.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://swapi.dev/documentation#people) you can get the records of all people using this endpoint:

`GET https://swapi.dev/api/people`

This allows you to build a simple caching: you could make this request on initializing your app (and/or periodically) and cache the response.
Then, instead of making separate requests for each `resident-link`, you just consult your cached people-data and do a simple filter/map to get the desired names:

```
const namesOnly = cachedPeopleData
                   .filter(person => residentUrls.includes(person.url))
                   .map(person => person.name);
```